# How to specify target with ExternalProject_Add?

Tags: cmake, external-project

Is it possible to build only a specific target when using ExternalProject? In particular, I need to download and build only the MPI version of the OpenCoarrays library. I tried

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  OpenCoarrays-fallback
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 1
  URL https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/opencoarrays/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz
  BUILD_COMMAND make caf_mpi
)
```

but it builds both serial and MPI versions. If it is not possible, any hack is also welcome.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`make install` installs all flows of `OpenCoarrays`, so even you build only `caf_mpi` at build stage, `caf_single` is built automatically on install stage.

For install only `caf_mpi` library flow you can try to modify package sources using `PATCH_COMMAND` argument of `ExternalProject_add` command.

E.g, you may replace content of `src/CMakeLists.txt` file to this one:

```
add_subdirectory(mpi)
```

Probably, this will work.

Comment: For now I've decided to redefine the install command with a simple `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy`, but I'll keep your suggestion also in mind.